# How to pause node.js app till debugger is attached

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, debugging, electron

I have a node.js app (electron, specifically) and want to debug it's earliest js code. I'm trying to use the `--debug-brk` switch:

```
electron --nolazy --debug-brk=5858 \git\electron-quick-start
```

The app doesn't start. So far, so good.
I then open Visual Studio's Attach to Process dialog, set the Transport to `Node.js remote debugging` and set the Qualifier to: `tcp://localhost:5858` and click Refresh.

Now the node.js app continues to launch. I haven't attached the debugger yet.

It seems node.js will not wait for the debugger to attach. The debugger simply querying the node.js process for a possible debuggee to attach to is sufficient to resume the app, which means I can't debug it fast enough, even with the `--debug-brk` switch.

Is there another way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Debugging the browser process doesn't work at the moment in Electron, put all your interesting code in the renderer process so you can use Devtools